# How can I build a work platform for reaching my ceiling?

Tags: woodworking

I know it might be a little bit of an open end question. To narrow this down I would mention that I am planning to use some 2x4s that I have laying around and some plywood to build two of the below work platforms. I might add some pads not to scratch the existing hardwood floor but that is the next project for the same room.

I do not want to buy one of these (the price is good -around 220CAD but it will force me to move very often.

[image]
I also considered renting a scaffolding tower (33CAD/day) but it is also short and too tall for my needs
https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/tool-and-vehicle-rental/p.scaffold-tower-5.11072.html

This is why I decided to build my own.

Is there a better way to build this ? I need the platforms to be long

[image]

Comment: Buy (or rent) a set of drywall stilts. Or rent a set of staging with wheels.

Comment: Think you might want it higher than just 1 foot.  Try a three/four foot step ladder to get a feel of working over head.  You want your arms to be comfortable working over head for long periods of time.  Would make it wider also to cut down on moving it.  Maybe a 1/2x1/2 piece at the edges, so you feet feel danger.

Comment: How long is your extension pole for your skim blade? Do you have stepladders and/or chairs available? I’ve had luck with 2x4’s    clamped between ladder steps and supported in the middle with chairs/buckets/whatever sturdy is on hand.

Comment: I am 6'2 myself so the height should be OK :-))
If I go wider it will be an issue to support my weight for that span. 
@Ecnerwal I added some details regarding the scaffolding and the renting option, not making sense.  I will need this over a week or so and I already have all the wood I  need for this

Comment: You're gonna need a bigger boat, I mean platform. Skim coating a ceiling requires a lot of moving around and you'll be concentrating of the ceiling, not where you're stepping. You'll also want someone mixing the plaster for you so you can keep spreading.

Comment: I will buy already mixed mud (general purpose USG mud is what I am considering) https://www.homedepot.ca/search?q=premixed%20mud#!q=premixed%20mud  
I can build two and set them side by side or maybe 4 ?

Comment: I could also 3 of these 4' long and use a sheet of construction plywood on top of them

Comment: OK I am reading that I need the ultra light joint compound https://www.homedepot.ca/product/cgc-sheetrock-ultralight-drywall-compound-11-5-l-pail/1000711841 ...comes premixed

Comment: Looking at the size you are thinking of, reminds me it is about the same size as a coffee table.   Make the frame nice with a rough top and when finish, put a nice top on.  Have a coffee table with 1/2 top and 1x3s under the edges about an inch inside on four legs.  Quite strong, but too nice to stand on with work boots.

Comment: My father in law [a professional plasterer his entire working life] used a couple of beer crates & a scaffold plank until stilts came out.

Comment: :-)) Bingo that is something that I can safely strap to my feet -two of those and I can walk the room as much as I like

Comment: @Tetsujin post it as answer please I will selected. This is genius https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hl8IFdLz9J8

Comment: Voting to close as too broad/open-ended.

Comment: The problem with a work platform that doesn't have railing is that you'll walk off the edge. That can be a body-jarring, if not head-knocking, drop.

Comment: If you try the milk crate idea, be very sure never to stand on the milk crate directly. The sides are strong enough to support weight, especially when the weight is spread across many of them, since crates were stacked.. but the bottoms are just strong enough to hold the contents of one crate pressing outward and _will_ fail if asked to cary more than that pressing inward.

Comment: Note too that for painting purposes, a roller with an extension pole works just fine. Plastering less so.

Comment: When I scraped the popcorn off my ceilings, I used old 5 gallon paint buckets and a 2x12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built something just like that and it works perfectly for my DIY ceilings all around the house.

Mine is 6ft long, the working platform is 1ft wide, and it is 23in high.

The height of the platform depends on your height of course. I made it so that when I stand on it there is a 2in gap between the top of my hair and the wet mud/paint. Those without hair or with hair that colour matches drywall compound can use a smaller gap ;)

What's important for safety and stability is to make sure that the base of the legs is much wider than the plank. The base of mine is 20in long, so it sticks out beyond the platform's long edge (making the design wider), by about 6in on both sides.

My design uses an old 2x12 plank as platform so I did not use joists.

Stabilize the corners with triangular (drawn) or rectangular cuts of plywood.

For moving this platform it is beneficial to consider in advance how and whether you'll take the legs off, and what maximum platform length will get you around corners of the house. For stability and safety I prefer a screwed-on platform over a plank placed on two boxes.

[image]

I build this and some exterior scaffolding because -with family and all- I did not want the time pressure that comes with renting.

Answer (score 0):

I would build two sturdy boxes big enough to support a pair of 2x10s or 2x12s.  Maybe a third box if you need center support.  Your boxes can be used to store your supplies and will be a lot easier to get into an out of a room than a large one piece platform.  If you want to spend the time and want to get fancy, you could make [Japanese tool boxes](https://makezine.com/projects/japanese-toolbox/) which make for great storage.